# Fortigate 40c Firewall Configuration

Tags: networking, security, firewall, dmz, fortinet

Does anybody know if is it possible to Un-bridge ports on forgiate 40c?

I want to use the fortigate 40c to define and control (block/allow) port traffic for the following 4 ip ranges (each ip range belongs to a different server).

1. port1 - 212.100.XXX.XXX
2. port2 - 63.245.XXX.XXX
3. port3 - 98.139.XXX.XXX
4. port4 - 74.125.XXX.XXX
5. port5 - 216.246.XXX.XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about your Fortigate HW 40C, but generally on Fortigate devices you need convert form Switching mode to Interface mode, for example by submitting CLI commands:

config system global
 set internal-switch-mode interface
 end

But prior this, you need clear/remove all configuration entries where "switch" is mentioned.
Typically: default firewall policy and DHCP setting on "Switch" interface.

BR 
Jan

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on the gui also, you'll still need to remove anything referencing the LAN though. Once all this is removed, an option for 'change mode' will appear in the interface menu.

warning: when this is applied, it will usually say "access denied" then auto reboot the device, but once you log back in the interfaces will have changed to routed mode.